# 2D list divided by another 2D list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2-D list:

```
A = [[10,20,30],
     [5,8,10]]

B = [[1,2,5],
     [5,4,2]]
```

The output should be:

```
result = [[10,10,6],
          [1,2,5]]
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
I could only think of nested for loop which is pretty complicated...

Comment: A nested loop is not complicated, it is the straight-forward way to do this. What exactly are you asking? Why is this tagged with `numpy`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the tag `numpy`, then use it.

If they're not already numpy arrays, first convert them:

```
A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
```

Then divide them:

```
>>> A / B
array([[10., 10.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  5.]])
>>>
```

As @sj95126 mentioned, to make it integer type values and a list, use:

```
>>> (A / B).astype(int).tolist()
[[10, 10, 6], [1, 2, 5]]
>>>
```

Or as @wjandrea mentioned, you could make them integers already in the beginning:

```
A = np.array(A, dtype='int')
B = np.array(B, dtype='int')
```

Then do:

```
>>> (A // B).tolist()
[[10, 10, 6], [1, 2, 5]]
>>>
```

Comment: Just to add a bit, to get the exact result specified in the question, you can convert the result like this: ```(A / B).astype(int).tolist()```.

Comment: Alternatively, keep them as ints from the start: `a, b = (np.array(x, dtype='int') for x in [A, B])` and use floor division: `(a // b).tolist()` -> `[[10, 10, 6], [1, 2, 5]]`.

Comment: @wjandrea Edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.floor_divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.floor_divide.html), which is equivalent to `//` and converts its inputs to arrays automatically:

```
>>> np.floor_divide(A, B)
array([[10, 10,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  5]])
```

A list comprehension would be a non-numpy solution free of libraries:

```
>>> [[a // b for a, b in zip(*rows)] for rows in zip(A, B)]
[[10, 10, 6], [1, 2, 5]]
```